# Plot network chain in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I want to plot an execution chain using graphs and python. I have to mantain left and right in the plotting, this is possible with networkx and matplotlib ?

Something like this:
[image]

I tryed:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5])
g.add_edge(1,3)
g.add_edge(2,3)
g.add_edge(3,5)
g.add_edge(3,4)

nx.draw(g,with_labels=True)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

but I don't know how to declare de order. I got:
[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Please include an example of your data. (Say, for the included graph.)

Comment: added to the post

Comment: I do not think you can do this in networkx.

Comment: any other known libray @DYZ ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, and requests for software recommendations are off topic on SO.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272710/networkx-how-to-assign-the-node-coordinates-as-attribute

Comment: Maybe topological sort is what you searching

Answer (score 1):

A network chain can be created using graphviz_layout in networkx.

**Install:**

- **pydot** to use write_dot(G, path)
- **pygraphviz** to use graphviz_layout(g, prog='dot')

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
g.add_edge(1,3)
g.add_edge(2,3)
g.add_edge(3,5)
g.add_edge(3,4)
g.add_edge(4,6)
g.add_edge(5,7)
g.add_edge(4,8)
g.add_edge(5,9)

nx.nx_pydot.write_dot(g,'DiGraph.dot')
pos = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(g, prog='dot')
nx.draw(g,pos,with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

**Returns:**

[image: Network Chain]