# Setting node locations with a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, graph, networkx

I have a dictionary with the following data:

```
pos = {0: (1,1), 1: (2,2), 2: (3,2), 3: (4,3)}
```

Then, I tried the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(pos)
#also G.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())
print(G.nodes(True))
```

which gives:

```
>>>> [(0, {}), (1, {}), (2, {}), (3, {})]
```

as you see, the positions are empty.

But if I write

```
G = nx.random_geometric_graph(5, 0.50)
print(G.nodes(True))
```

it returns

```
[(0, {'pos': [0.895101164279736, 0.43929155577155976]}), (1, {'pos': [0.006064168598946429, 0.6044775286563574]}), (2, {'pos': [0.021659978032451344, 0.47877598747213523]}), (3, {'pos': [0.05130150282000934, 0.1137451989310001]}), (4, {'pos': [0.8734509206210705, 0.9839817045923323]})]
```

it is, a graph with locations.
Also I tried changing ´pos´ to ´pos2´ :

```
pos2 = {0:{'pos': [1,1]}, 1: {'pos':[2,2]}, 2: {'pos':[3,2]}, 3: {'pos':[4,3]}}
```

and I tried too the codes from other related questions:

1) [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806811/4959345)

```
for n, p in pos.iteritems():
    X.node[n]['pos'] = p
```

2) [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42273977/4959345)

```
pos={'0':(1,0),'1':(1,1),'2':(2,3),'3':(3,2),'4':(0.76,1.80),'5':(0,2)}
```

nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'coord', pos)

I have to add more than 1500 nodes to a graph with labels multiple times, so I dont want to use a ´for´ loop, I'm looking for efficient asigment, not like:

```
G2.add_node(1,pos=(1,0))
```

Can anyone find a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set all nodes' `position` attributes at once through [`function.set_node_attributes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html), which takes a `values` parameter that can be a dictionary with the structure `{node0: {'attr1': 20, 'attr2': 'nothing'}, node1: {'attr2': 3}}`. Hence in this example you could directly do:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(pos)
G.nodes(True)
# NodeDataView({0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}})
```

Now we can feed `function.set_node_attributes` directly the dictionary as:

```
pos = {0: (1,1), 1: (2,2), 2: (3,2), 3: (4,3)}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, pos, 'pos')
```

And now by printing the `NodeDataView` you'd get:

```
G.nodes(True)
# NodeDataView({0: {'pos': (1, 1)}, 1: {'pos': (2, 2)}, 2: {'pos': (3, 2)}, 3: {'pos': (4, 3)}})
```

---

So if you were to draw the graph, you could set the positions in the `pos` parameter of `nx.draw`:

```
nx.draw(G, node_color='lightblue', with_labels=True, pos=pos, node_size=500)
```

[image]

Comment: what abbout `nx.draw(G)`, it return a circular graph perhaps the set locations, should it not do the same as `nx.draw(G,pos)` ?

Comment: `nx.draw(G)` will set the locations randomly. You need to feed it the dictionary. I've updated @luis